I need help to convert .textpb to json with nested input
I need help to convert .textpb to json with nested input.
I tried various tools with python  but doesnt work since .textpb or .pb is nested and so output data is not correct in json
Pls find the file location below and anyone help pls
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/refs/heads/main/assets/latest_carrier_id

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"pb" and "textpb" refer to Protocol Buffers.

NOTE "textpb" likely refers to Protocol Buffers Text Format which is... less useful.

The "pb" file is a binary file corresponding to the encode Protocol Buffer "Messages" and you will need Protocol Buffer (aka "protobuf") tools to completely decode the file.
Protocol Buffers are defined using a text-based schema. I looked -- but was unable to find -- the schema that corresponds to "carrier_list.pb". Usually the schema is either referenced from or included in the repo(s) that uses the schema.
It would be helpful if you could find the Protocol Buffer schema document that corresponds to this binary file.
Without the schema file, you can decode the binary files but these will be loss-less (no field names, some ambiguity) etc.
You can try pasting carrier_list.pb into this online Protocol Buffer Decoder.
There are two others way that you can use the Protocol Buffers tool (protoc). Either by downloading it from the Protocol Buffers repo.
cat /path/to/carrier_list.pb \
| protoc \
--decode_raw

If you find the schema you can use protoc to decode the same file using it but it's more difficult to provide you with the command-line, something along the lines of:
cat /path/to/carrier_list.pb \
| protoc \
  --proto_path=/path/to/protos \
  --decode=package.Message \
  /path/to/protos/carrier.proto

Or, since you reference Python, you can use gRPC tooling (this builds upon protocol buffers):
python3 -m pip install grpcio
python3 -m pip install grpcio-tools

cat /path/to/carrier_list.pb \
| python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc \
--decode_raw

Found Carrier Identification but still no Protocol Buffer schema.
